# How to connect socket io nodejs in java

Tags: java, node.js, socket.io

when I tried to connect nodejs from java I am getting this error :

> engine intercepting request for path "/socket.io/" +3m
>   engine handling "GET" http request "/socket.io/1/" +0ms
>   engine unknown transport "undefined" +0ms

Here is my sample :

```
package basic;
public class BasicExample implements IOCallback {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new BasicExample();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public BasicExample() throws Exception {
        SocketIO socket = new SocketIO("my nodejs path");
        socket.connect(new IOCallback() {       
            public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {

            }       
            public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {

            }       
            public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {              
            }       
            public void onDisconnect() {                
            }       
            public void onConnect() {               
            }   
            public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {               
            }
        });
        socket.send("Hello Server");
        socket.send(new JSONObject().put("key", "value").put("key2",
                "another value"));
        socket.emit("event", "argument1", "argument2", 13.37);
}
    public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
        System.out.println("Server said: " + data);
    }

    public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
        System.out.println("an Error occured");
        socketIOException.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void onDisconnect() {
        System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
    }
    public void onConnect() {
        System.out.println("Connection established");
    }

    public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
        System.out.println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like the URL you are using to connect to does not contain the right transport.  Here's an example of a socket.io connection URL: `ws://192.168.1.155/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=iiNFtO9DiqbftNOwAAAJ`.  This is an http request that tells the socket.io engine which transports the user wants to use.

Comment: FYI, one thing you can do is connection to your node.js server using the socket.io Javascript library from a webpage (it takes only a couple lines of code) and then look at the network requests sent from browser to the socket.io server.  Compare that to what you're doing in your Java client.